# Python Sum values of duplicated keys in array

Tags: python

I have this list below I need to sum the RT and LT values:

```
Type   RT     LT     NAID   RecordTime
"T"   "15"  "123"   "NZ45"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"T"   "56"  "480"   "NZ45"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"T"   "90"  "480"   "CR98"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"S"   "80"  "180"   "RU992" "2018-05-30 16:58:00"
```

I'm capable to sum the RT but not both at the same time, using the below code, the list above is save in the variable called "rows":

```
class tmonCon():
timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.DEBUG):
    formatter = logging.Formatter(' %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler = logging.FileHandler('C:\\config\\' + log_file)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger

# conection to the database to get the Webtmon details
try:
    connect = psycopg2.connect("dbname='TMONNETWarehouse' user='postgres' 
 host='localhost' password='$$$$$$$'")
except:
    print ("I am unable to connect to the database")
# Read the db and assign the details to a variable
cur = connect.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT "Type","Realtime", "LowerBoundary", "NAID", "RecordTime" FROM "Boundaries" """)
rows = cur.fetchall()
logSearch = setup_logger('tmonSearch', 'tmonSearch')
for row in (rows):
    logSearch.info(', '.join ((str(r) for  r in row))) 

sumarized = defaultdict(int)
for T,R,L,NAID,RT in rows:
    sumarized[NAID, T, RecT] +=RT
print(sumarized)
```

This works for the RT but I need to summarize LT as well

```
sumarized = defaultdict(int)
for Type,RT,LT,NAID,RecT in rows:
    sumarized[NAID, RecT] +=RT, =+LT
```

This does not work and I'm not sure what to do to summarize the RT and LT

Comment: Can you please format your code? Also, is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Please check your code for typos.

Comment: This is a query asked from a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting your defaultdict to `int`, you can only store an integer for each key in the dictionary. I'm not sure if you want to sum RT and LT, or generate separate counts for each.

To combine RT and LT as a single value:

```
sumarized = defaultdict(int)
for Type,RT,LT,NAID,RecT in rows:
    sumarized[NAID, RecT] += RT + LT
print(sumarized)
```

output (formatted for easier reading):

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {
  ('NZ45', '2018-05-30 16:59:00'): 674,
  ('CR98', '2018-05-30 16:59:00'): 570,
  ('RU992', '2018-05-30 16:58:00'): 260
})
```

To keep the values separate, you'll need to add something to the keys to distinguish between the two:

```
for T,RT,LT,NAID,RecT in data:
    sumarized[NAID, RecT, 'RT'] += RT
    sumarized[NAID, RecT, 'LT'] += LT
print(sumarized)
```

output (formatted for easier reading):

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {
  ('NZ45', '2018-05-30 16:59:00', 'RT'): 71, 
  ('NZ45', '2018-05-30 16:59:00', 'LT'): 603,
  ('CR98', '2018-05-30 16:59:00', 'RT'): 90,
  ('CR98', '2018-05-30 16:59:00', 'LT'): 480,
  ('RU992', '2018-05-30 16:58:00', 'RT'): 80,
  ('RU992', '2018-05-30 16:58:00', 'LT'): 180
})
```

If you want some other type of data arrangement you can alter your defaultdict keys/value/set up accordingly.

Comment: Do you know other method to sum both values and keep them in the same row? Not necessarily defaultdict

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want to produce from the data you're extracting from the DB? How I'd structure the data would be very dependent on (a) any extra calculations I wanted to do with the db data, and (b) what parts of the resulting data I need to use further.

Comment: Let me ask a new question