# Python sum two columns based on array key

Tags: python

I have the following:

`Type   RT     LT     NAID   RecordTime
"T"   "15"  "123"   "NZ45"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"S"   "34"  "210"   "NZ45"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"T"   "56"  "480"   "NZ45"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"T"   "90"  "480"   "CR98"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"S"   "80"  "180"   "RU992" "2018-05-30 16:58:00"`

And I need to sum the RT and LT values based on the Type column and the NAID as you can see below sum the values for the same type and NAID.

`Type   RT     LT     NAID   RecordTime
"T"   "71"  "603"   "NZ45"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"S"   "34"  "210"   "NZ45"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"T"   "90"  "480"   "CR98"  "2018-05-30 16:59:00"
"S"   "80"  "180"   "RU992" "2018-05-30 16:58:00"`

Could you give me a hand?

Comment: What does "column" mean? A list, a csv file, a pandas dataframe? And what have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: I have tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510081/python-sum-values-of-duplicated-keys-in-array/51510882#51510882

Comment: Is the `RecordTime` column to be ignored in deciding which rows to add? I.e. does that column decide (in part) whether two rows are to be added? If not, if that column differs between the two rows, which value should be kept?

Comment: @JohnRodriguez Do not post code in a comment. You can't format it properly. Please edit your question instead.

Comment: I just need to sum RT and LT values where the NAID is the same.

Comment: I just need to sum RT and LT values where the NAID is the same. And keep of the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your data is coming out of a database, but I've put it into a list of lists to mimic the effect.

```
rows = [["T","15","123","NZ45","2018-05-30 16:59:00"],
["S","34","210","NZ45","2018-05-30 16:59:00"],
["T","56","480","NZ45","2018-05-30 16:59:00"],
["T","90","480","CR98","2018-05-30 16:59:00"],
["S","80","180","RU992","2018-05-30 16:58:00"]]

rslts = {}
for Type,RT,LT,NAID,RecT in rows:
    # create a unique key for each combination of NAID, Type, and RecT
    key = "_".join([NAID, Type, RecT])

    if key in rslts:
         # we have seen this combination before: add LT and RT to the existing LT and RT
         rslts[key]["RT"] += int(RT)
         rslts[key]["LT"] += int(LT)  
    else:
        # if we haven't seen this combination before, add the record under the unique key
        rslts[key] = { "NAID": NAID, "RecT": RecT, "Type": Type, "RT": int(RT), "LT": int(LT) }

# print out the data
print( "\t".join( ['Type','RT','LT','NAID','RecT'] ) )
for k in rslts:
    print( "\t".join( map(lambda x: str(rslts[k][x]), ['Type','RT','LT','NAID','RecT'] ) ) )
```

Output:

```
Type    RT  LT  NAID    RecT
T       71  603 NZ45    2018-05-30 16:59:00
S       34  210 NZ45    2018-05-30 16:59:00
T       90  480 CR98    2018-05-30 16:59:00
S       80  180 RU992   2018-05-30 16:58:00
```

Note that I had to cast LT and RT as integers to perform the addition, and as strings to print them out. If LT and RT are coming out of your DB as integers, you might not need to do that step.

Comment: Genius.Thanks Mr I alarmed Alien